# Jquery slide-bar works on local but not online

Tags: jquery, syntax, web, syntax-error

site:
nellysapotilledesign.com

I put my website online to check the animation, my jquery is not working online but it definitely working on local view can someone help me please and tell me what is wrong

Comment: Check the console: `Uncaught TypeError: $.slidebars is not a function`

Comment: where should I find this code, in my js file?

Comment: thank you robert rosas I made the changes but still not working

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the following script:

```
<script src="javascript/slidebars.js"></script>
```

Try loading it from a CDN, like this way:

- Full Script(Development)

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidebars/0.10.2/slidebars.js"></script>
  ```
- Minified Version(Production)

  ```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slidebars/0.10.2/slidebars.min.js"></script>
  ```